# Aligning buttons in a html table. IE problems (Staircase Issue)

Tags: html, button, input, html-table

I have a html table which contains large blocks of information. Above this I have 3 input buttons which were initially in a different table. 2 of the buttons were on the left with a line of text in front of them and the third button was over to the right.

It looked like this:

---------------- indicates space

```
asdas [button] [button]---------------------[button]

+----------------------------------------------++--------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------------++--------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------------++--------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------------++--------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------------++--------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------------++--------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------------++--------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------------++--------------------------------+
```

What I wanted to do was align the third button with the right hand side of the left module. The table below the buttons is a simple one which are split two `<td>`'s.

What I did was I put another row on the table and put the buttons in the first td. I then used style="float: right;" on the third button to move it over. This worked in Firefox but in IE the button dropped down slightly below the other buttons(although it was still aligned right). I can't go changing the CSS files so has anyone got any other work around solutions to right align the button with the left side of the table below and keep in on the same line? All the buttons are in the same cell.

Here is the html I am currently using for the table:

```
<table id="" summary="">
  <tr>
    <td class="">
      Text: <input type="button" class="" value="" onclick="" />
      &nbsp;
      <input type="button" class="" value="" onclick="" />
      &nbsp;
      <input type="button" class="" style="float:right;" value="" onclick="" />
    </td>
    <td class="">
      &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So I managed to solve this myself. I added a div between the first 2 buttons and the 3rd. I used float:left on the first div and float:right on the second div and that elminated the staircase problem

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to place the buttons in the same table, you can choose to put a 'text-align: right;' on the table cell in which your third button is placed. This should place your button to the right of the cell on the same horizontal line as the other buttons.

Comment: All 3 buttons are in the same cell. I tried to create a smaller table inside that cell but encountered the same problem

Comment: My apologies, in my head I had already placed the third button inside the second cell. I see you have solved your question already.